# NullPointerException at the call of getDefaultSharedPreference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This is what I've declared in my ContactActivity class

```
final SharedPreferences exceptionPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
exceptionPrefs.edit().putString("Exceptions", TextUtils.join(",", exceptions)).apply();
```

In a different class (which is not an activity. It extends `BroadcastReceiver`), on trying to get the stored values from `SharedPreference` I'm using this within `onReceive()` -

```
SharedPreferences exceptionPositionPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(new ContactActivity().getContext());
```

That very line throws a NullPointerException.

Also, I must add that onReceive contains of another SharedPreferences object, which receives values from my `MainActivity`.

Here's the LogCat.

```
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.scimet.admin.driveon.RejectCall: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2146)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:371)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at com.scimet.admin.driveon.RejectCall.onReceive(RejectCall.java:36)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2139)
10-19 15:49:03.628: E/AndroidRuntime(24226):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: `new ContactActivity()`... You don't *create* Activities in Android.

Comment: @S.D. How else do I pass in the context of ContactActivity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferences you use are shared between all activities.

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
```

The above will return the **same preferences** if `ctx` is MainActivity or ContactActivity.

So basically you can just call it from the BroadcastReceiver with what ever context you have available.

---

That being said if you want to get activity-dependent preferences you should be calling `Context.getPreferences()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should never instantiate an activity class and get the context from there. In fact you shouldn't instantiate an activity period; you should use startActivity to handle the activity lifecycle.

Why are you doing that anyway, the BroadcastReceiver does get a context supplied to the onReceive method, can't you just use that context to retrieve your SharedPreference?

Comment: That's a MainActivity context, which I'm also using for a different SharedPreferences object.

Comment: You should get the same SharedPreference with 'getDefaultSharedPreferences'. Can you try to use the way I suggested and see if it works? It should work unless I'm misreading your question somehow

Comment: What I mean to say is, My onReceive method has two SharedPreference objects. One of them uses the MainActivity context (which is what I presume is passed as an argument to onReceive, since MainActivity is the launcher activity). The other `SharedPreference` (which is what gives the NullPointerException) is used for receiving data from `ContactActivity` class. There's no alternative way I can think of, to give in the context of `ContactActivity`, except by instantiating it and using it's `getContext()` method which I declared within `ContactActivity`

Comment: Please post what you are doing after the point where you are getting the null pointer. How are you using "exceptionPositionPrefs"?